# how to sum of records

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sum, foxpro

i have table in which there no. of transactions in many accounts .... how to sum of all transaction according to account wise....as well as i want to display sum of all transactions account num wise of all account number
for ex..

```
account_num     transaction_amt
001                200 
001                300
002                330
002                400
```

and so on
i want to display as

```
account_num     total_transaction
001               500
002               730
```

and so on
please help me out

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT account_num, sum(transaction_amt) as total_transaction 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY account_num
```

Then press F1 and look at the help under 'SQL-Select'.